# Get salary increase after probation even if increase are annually given

Tags: salary, negotiation, probation

I just finished my 3 months probation on my work this week. I have not been asked to give up my projects and equipments given by the company, and have also worked well for the past 3 months so I am pretty sure that I'll be a regular/permanent come next week.

My question is, how can I effectively ask for a raise in my salary since I am now a regular in our company even if the salary raise are done in our company yearly. When I was offered this job, the salary that was offered to me was below my expected rate though I accepted the job because I really wanted it and I gave up negotiation for my salary when they said it was just my initial salary. I might have mistook/misunderstood by what they said as initial salary as I expected that I'll get a raise when my probation ends but didn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My question is, how can I effectively ask for a raise in my salary
>   since I am now a regular in our company even if the salary raise are
>   done in our company yearly.

You made a mistake by assuming you would get a raise at the end of your probation, rather than asking about that specifically (when in doubt, don't assume - ask!). If you knew then that you must live with this low salary for a year, you still would have "really wanted the job", right? Would you have turned down the offer? But it's done, so that doesn't matter now. Now, you need to move on.

You can still find a quiet time to ask your boss about a review, and ask about a raise during that review. You may find that you will indeed get a raise at that time.

But be prepared if the answer is "No. You must wait until the annual increase period".

Decide beforehand if this is something you can live with or not. Then act on your decision.

If you decide to move on, make sure you understand the details of your next offer before you accept it, so you don't end up with similar regrets.

Answer (score 3):

If there isn't one scheduled, I'd advise having a performance review soon where you ask for feedback about how are things going and if they are going well then ask for a raise now that you are off probation. The idea here is to have a basis for why you deserve the raise. If you've done work that exceeded expectations then you may have a better position than if your work is just acceptable.

Remember that the key here is to discuss that your past performance is good and thus you believe a raise is merited and since you started outside of the annual system, you'd like a raise soon. At least this would be how I'd handle it and if you can't get a raise, then possibly ask if you could get a bonus for the good work you've done. The key is to have something to justify the additional funds.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked at a few locations where My expectations involving pay, hours and workload were no in line with the companies and I had find a way to alter either my expectations or my work situation.  Here are a few of the things that I learned:

- Make sure that you talk about your expectations from the get go.
- If a raise was not established in you initial meeting, then it is a very hard sell afterwards.
- Its never too late to start talking about your expectations.
- Keep your conversation about pay very 'matter-of-fact'.
- Don't make it personal.
- Focus on you needs instead of wants.
- Make sure that you can back up your request with past performance.
- It is difficult to show major value in the first three months.
- Try to keep options open. No does not mean never, just not right now.
- If you goal is not immediately forthcoming, try to build a road map.
- If the answer is no, accept you bosses decision, but try to get a feel for when to readdress it.
- Show your resolve, but also show a willingness to cooperate.

Answer (score 2):

You should feel free to ask for a raise any time you want.

Any time you feel you are being underpaid, you are doing your manager a favor by asking for a raise because it gives him or her a chance to address the issue before you quit or are whisked away by recruiters.

Simply drop in on your boss or appropriate authority in their office, make sure your timing is appropriate by asking if this is a good time, and then firmly ask for your requested amount.

They may or may not give it to you, but that is a good way going about asking.